# Add comma after two/three places for currency in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I want to add comma to my currency value at 3rd or 2nd place as per the currency value:
the output should be like this:

```
1000 => 1000
10000 => 10,000
210000 => 2,10,000
2010000 => 20,10,000
12010000 => 1,20,10,000
```

I am using Numeral.js plugin to do my conversion. but the plugin adds commas only after 3 digits.the output is like:

200,000,000 for input 200000000

this is the code I am using.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function() {
            $('.currency').keyup(function(event){
             if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40){
                event.preventDefault();
             }
             var $this = $(this);
             var num = $this.val();
             var num2 = numeral(num).format('0,0[.]00');
             console.log(num2);
             $this.val(num2);
            });
        });
</script>
```

I wouldn't mind regex, but I couldn't find any which could do this.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I don't follow the use case?

Comment: what currency are you using ?

Comment: From your examples it looks like it's using the wrong locale for its conversion. So... can Numeral.js use different locales?

Comment: I am using the us locale in numeral. but my locale is indian. yes numeral can use different locals but indian is not one of them.

Comment: @user2933671 So it can't output that particular format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution,

Should work up to 9 digits[jsfiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/rainerpl/spbWH/3/)

```
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    var res = [], nr;
    x = x.split("").reverse().join("");
    nr = x.match(/[0-9]{1,3}/g);
    console.log("first split" , nr);
    if (x.length < 4) {return nr[0].split("").reverse().join('');}
    else if (x.length < 9) {
        res.push( nr.shift() );//last three digits
        //join and split the remainder at 2 digits

        nr = nr.join('').match(/[0-9]{1,2}/g);

        res = res.concat(nr);
        console.log(res);
        return res.join(',').split("").reverse().join("");
    } else {
        return nr.join(',').split("").reverse().join('');
    }
}
function handleInput(evt) {
    $('#result').text( numberWithCommas( $('#input').val() ));
}
$('#input').keyup(handleInput);
```

Comment: Since I am dealing with currencies. I dont know how many digits the user will enter. and I cant also restrict him/her to 9 digits. anyways. thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
function numberWithCommas(x) 
{
    var parts = x.toString().split(".");
    parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    return parts.join(".");
}
```

try this...

Comment: 1,0,0,0,000    --- after 3 digits it adds comma after every 1 digit. where as after 3 digits it should add comma after every 2 digit.

Answer (score 0):

With string operations in a `while` loop

```
var intPart = '12010000',
    i = intPart.length - 3,
    str = intPart.slice(-3);
if (i > 0) {
    while ((i-=2)>=0) {
        str = intPart.slice(i, i+2) + ',' + str;
    }
    if (i === -1) str = intPart.slice(0, 1) + ',' + str;
}
str; // "1,20,10,000"
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this change using the code above

```
function numberWithCommas(x) 
{
    var parts = x.toString().split(".");
    parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/^(\d*)(\d\d)(\d\d\d$|\d\d\.)/g, "$1$2,$3");
    return parts.join(".");
}
```